# What is the humble way to say 'I would like to introduce myself'

Tags: career-development

Here is the situation: I am asking advice from a person who is much senior than me in a letter.

I want to express 'Before telling you my question, I would like to tell you something about myself/introduce a little bit about myself '. Then the next paragraph is about my experience in the university.

But I would like to say it in a very humble and respectful way, what would be a good expression? Can I say "I would like to draw a rough picture about myself"?

**Update:

Thank you guys for answering and commenting about my problem.
I think I may not say it clearly. I am not asking questions, I am asking career advice from a senior stranger. So how to introduce myself?
Thanks**

Comment: Could you add a country tag? I would _never_ think about introducing myself _humbly_.

Comment: What is your professional relationship with this person, and what kind of advice are you asking them for?

Comment: What's wrong with "I would like to introduce myself"?

Comment: @OmarL - what's wrong with it is that if you fill up emails with fluff like that, folks will instantly delete the emails

Comment: @Fattie: It could be because it is poorly formatted and lacks a lot of significant context. I didn't downvote, but I also don't think the question (as it is) is very good.

Comment: @JoelEtherton you could be right that that is the reason. FYI when I see a question that is badly written (perhaps by a non-natice English speaker) I just edit to fix the grammar etc.  In fact, this question to me seems pretty clearly written/formatted? (Perhaps someone has fixed it up already, IDK)

Comment: @Fattie: For me it mostly lacks a lot of context that would make it meaningful, and only OP can provide that context.

Comment: Start with , Your Most Excellent Majesty (insert name here), I hope your highness will condescend to peruse my meagre...etc,.

Comment: Could you update this with a country tag? Advice that is perfect for someone in country A could be horribly bad for someone in country B.

Answer (score 9):

I recommend you avoid "meta talk" like "I am going to ask you a question" or "first, let me tell you about myself." It's pretty normal to introduce yourself to a stranger when you email them out of the blue, so don't take up space explaining that you're doing a normal thing.

So write your email something like this:

> Professor Smith,

> My name is Sam Zhao. [A sentence or two about you that should make it obvious why you're asking, for example you're studying a field in which they are a luminary.]

> Do you think that X is more important than Y? [or whatever your question is, expressed as a single short sentence.] [Add more details about what you've discovered so far or why this particular question is important to you. Think about it like a Stack Exchange question, don't just lob something really vague and open ended at them and expect a many paragraph dissertation in return.]

> [close with some sort of expression of gratitude that is not "thanks in advance" -- thank them for reading or for being an inspiration or for what they've already done for your field]

> Sam Zhao

I get emails from strangers asking me things all the time and I appreciate it if they tell me about themselves, since that will affect how I reply to them. I don't appreciate it if they clutter up the email with a lot of stuff about how I don't know them, but they really want to email me, and they want to ask me something, but first they need to do another thing, and then finally "my question is". Take some time to write something that makes sense in the order it appears. An email shouldn't need a table of contents or reader's guide.

Best of luck reaching out to this person.

Comment: Kate, humorously, your answer is the same as mine, but yours has a lot of metatalk  :)  :)

Comment: Thank you, I think I didn't explain the scenario well, I just updated the question!

Comment: It changes nothing if it's career advice. Your question might be "should I learn X" or "should I get Y kind of experience." The email structure is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **DON'T** waste words on introducing that topic. (Or any topic.)

So, YES:

> Steve, I have a question about XYZ. I'm a PhD in ABC working for Jack in DEF. Should I renormalize the ..

No:

> Steve, I have a question about XYZ. I will explain who I am. I'm a PhD in ABC working for Jack in DEF. My question. Should I renormalize the ..